# Multilingual Issues with WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, multilingual

I am trying to set up one WordPress site that allows the user to choose what language they want to see their content in. I am wondering how I would go about showing navigation menus in the language of their choice. Where would I be able to have multiple values for a single menu item (one per language) in the administration area and how would WordPress know which one of these to use?

Are there plugins which allow for this? If not, do you have any suggestions for what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is internationalization.  As a developer you would use the Wordpress Gettext libraries.  You should check out the [official Wordpress developer reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/) on the subject the implementation details and use of these libraries.